# mysql select number changes union two tables

Tags: mysql

table `a` shows user current selecting item (contains: selected_date, item_id)
which is added after user selected a item

table `b` shows user unselected history (contains: selected_date, unselected_date, item_id)
which is added after user unselected a item

I want to show the selected count changes of all items between date `r` and `y`
just like:

```
item_id |  change
1       |  +1
2       |  -3
3       |  +10
```

tables:

```
create table a (
user_id int,
item_id int ,
selected_date date,

)

create table b (
item_id int,
selected_date date,
unselected_date date,
primary key(item_id, selected_date)
);
```

sample data:

```
a:
+-------+--------------+
|item_id|selected_date |
+-------+--------------+
|     48|2022-03-17    |
|     49|2022-03-17    |
+-------+--------------+   

b:
+-------+--------------+---------------+
|item_id|selected_date |unselected_date|
+-------+--------------+---------------+
|     47|2022-03-14    |2022-03-17     |
|     48|2020-03-11    |2022-03-12     |
|     49|2021-03-17    |2022-03-14     |
+-------+--------------+---------------+
```

Output:

```
if r = 2022-03-15, y = 2022-03-17
+-------+------+
|item_id|change|
+-------+------+
|     47|-1    |
|     48|+2    |
|     49|+1    |
+-------+------+
```

[image: What I am thinking about]

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO with sample data (5-10 rows per table), dates range and desired output.

Comment: The sample values are confusing.  Shouldn't there be a "selected" row in table A for item_id = 47? Also, why is the selected date for item_id=48 "2022-03-17", but in table B it's "2022-03-11"?
What are your expected results for the sample data?

Comment: Could you clarify the question (give us more information what is purpose of it etc.). With the information that you posted, it looks like you have duplicated data in your database. You should have only single table (like `b`) with NULL-able `unselected_date` column. (And view declared as `create view a as select * from b where unselected_date is null` if you need the table `a` for simplification of the application code.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I should explain my problem more detail.

I need to union two query of table a and b into:

```
select (date), (sum of changes)
```

a means changes +1

and b means changes -1


Therefore, if day `y` has 4 rows of a and 2 rows of b. (selected_date = `y`)

It should get:

```
+----+-------+
|date|changes|
+----+-------+
|   y|+2     |
+----+-------+
```

### My solution

As jiwopene said, I mix table `a` and `b` into one table.

It has `selected_date` and nullable `unselected_date`.

Finally, get the sum of changes using `case`

```
select date, sum(num) from (
    select a.selected_date as date, 
        case
            when a.unselected_date is null then 1
            else -1
        end as num
    from a
) as sq
group by date;
```